# Loading view on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am attempting to show a loading view on top of a UITableViewController when a user taps on a cell or a button in the cell. For some reason, the view does not show up, nor does it show any constraint failures. Can someone spot error in my code. I need this view to show up covering the tableview on both orientations, when shown. I thought this to be a view render issue, tried the same code in viewWillAppear. Still does not work. Hence I eliminated layout rendering issues. Same code works perfectly fine on UIViewController derived classes. Seems to have issues on UITableViewController classes alone!!!

```
private func initActivityView() {
    let overlayView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    overlayView.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(overlayView)
    // add constraints
    let viewDictionary = ["overlayView":overlayView]

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[overlayView]-0-|", 
        options: .AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[overlayView]-0-|", 
        options: .AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
}
```

Comment: why do u give CGRectZero ?

Comment: Does not make any difference if I just say UIView() or UIView(frame: CGRectZero). I tried both

Comment: u need to give the view frame cgrectmake(x,y,w,h)

Comment: If I am going to give that, why do I need auto-layout?

Comment: autolayout is to fit the view for diff screen  sizes.

Comment: Even If I do this let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds) or let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame). Does not make any difference. View does not show up

Comment: i see, u r trying to resizer the view based on constraints. You need to call layoutIfneeded after u apply the constraints

Comment: add this line self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after u apply constraints and  see if it works for u or not

Comment: I tried that earlier. Did not work. Move the entire code in to ViewWillAppear. Still does not work. If I make one subtle change it does work 
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[overlayView(>=200)]-0-|", options: .AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[overlayView(>=200)]-0-|", options: .AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))

Answer (score 0):

You should let the constraints engine know that it needs update. See the triggering Auto layout section of the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints). Also I would consider making your overlay view an instance variable or find some other way to keep a reference of it so that when the time comes you can remove it.

Do **not** call `updateConstraints()` but rather `setNeedsUpdateContraints()`

From the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints).

> Discussion 
>   When a property of your custom view changes in a way that
>   would impact constraints, you can call this method to indicate that
>   the constraints need to be updated at some point in the future. The
>   system will then call updateConstraints as part of its normal layout
>   pass. Updating constraints all at once just before they are needed
>   ensures that you don’t needlessly recalculate constraints when
>   multiple changes are made to your view in between layout passes.

If your having trouble yo can always set a breakpoint on the UIViewController's 
[viewWillLayoutSubViews()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) and [viewDidLayoutSubViews()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) and inspect your subview frames.

It is also pretty helpful to keep update with [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/io%E2%80%A6) for  Auto Layout as Auto Layout is constantly changing and improving.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently doing it the autolayout way will not work, due to the inherent nature of UITableViewController. However a better solution for this problem will be something like this

```
let overlayView1 = UIView(frame: self.tableView.frame)
overlayView1.autoresizingMask = self.tableView.autoresizingMask
overlayView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
overlayView1.alpha = 0.5

self.tableView.addSubview(overlayView1)
```